# Do Session variables expire after different amount of time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

In my Login page I put connection string and the logged in user role in to session variables. To check if the session has not expired I put the following lines of code into the page_load event of the other pages.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["userRole"])==null
      Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

   .........
}
```

But I get `Session[conString] is expired` error sometimes when the web application is idle for a while. Now I wonder if the expiration times are different for different session variables. If not, then shouldn't I be redirected to the Login page when the application detects that the session is expired?

Comment: Try logging the Session["userRole"] and see what value is logged when the Connection string expires. Actually, the session variables does not expire, but the session does.

Comment: If the application restarts due to a change to web.config or the application pools recycles then the session is lost as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the idle timeout of your application is shorter than the session timeout. Meaning that the web server will kill your app if it's idle before the time you specified for your session to expire.

And no, the session variables do not expire. The session does (after the specified timeout).

Comment: So the idle timeout and the session timeout are completely two different things? I didn't know that.Thank you for this clue.

Comment: @MikeJM - Yes, the idle timeout is something that you can set in IIS (the web server), and the session timeout is something that is part of the configuration of your application.